# Time needed to get your flag approved

Tags: support, flagging, moderation

What is the longest (or shortest time) you have to wait before getting your flag approved or rejected?

I have raised the flag on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2693593/a-gambling-problem) as "unclear what you are asking" and have waited for four days but there are still no reply, while on my other flags, only about half an hour to a maximum of a few hours I have to wait until it is approved.

Comment: I've experienced similar variability in flag resolution times.  In many cases the flag may be approved or rejected based on the reviews by other users, and in some cases the flag will only be resolved by Moderator actions.

Comment: It would usually take less than an hour, or longest a few hours. If I see a flag that remains pending for a few days then it may have been ignored entirely.

Comment: I assume you were asking a Question here.  I have had flags resolved in as little as an hour and as long as a few days, so your experience is in line with mine.

Comment: The reason ought to be that you flagged the post before it was asked! :-) "have waited for four days" vs " asked 2 days ago roskiller"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question depends on which type of flag we are talking about. For the flags that are handled by moderators the average handling time is currently less than an hour (the median should be still lower).

There is not really a shortest or longest time in any meaningful sense. Sometimes it will be near instantly sometimes an issue could be kept open for days (this happens mostly if one mod wants others to also see the thing).

However, you are asking about a close flag and those are not dealt with by moderators, but (indirectly) via the close review-queue and close votes.

The reason your flag is still open is that the post is neither:

- voted to close for your reason
- closed (for any reason)
- through review

I don't really know why this one takes relatively long for being reviewed. (Could be the rare tag and the confusedness of the question.)
The reason why no one voted for your reason might be that you actually flagged for a reason other then the one you state now (you flagged 'too broad').

As you see one vote can suffice for marking the flag helpful, so this can go quickly. But the full review process can take longer. Again there are no actual thresholds.

That said, your flag did already have some effect. Namely, it placed the question in the review-queue.

Comment: I have two unreviewed flags, one for "unclear what you are asking" and one for "too broad".

Comment: Edit to the comment above (and a bit too late to edit directly): the "unclear what you are asking" is removed by myself because I think I have waited for too long.

Comment: Not on the question you asked about though. It does not really matter much; though had you flagged the one you had flagged "too broad" as "unclear" the flag would be cleared as "helpful" since  awhile. Either way I'll deal with those question now.